# How to implement autocomplete google place api in toolbar - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-places-api, android-toolbar

I am implementing a restaurant based application in which I am typing place name in toolbar
I am not able to implement autocomplete feature in App toolbar.....  *Please help*

**menu xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/my_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:title="My Location" />
    <item android:id="@+id/my_location"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_gps_fixed_24"
        android:title="My Location" />
</menu>
```

**java code**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       

   }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared an Action Provider in your menu xml so the system doesn't know that you're trying to utilize a search interface in your toolbar. Add an `actionViewClass` attribute to your menu item. It should look something like this:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/my_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
    android:title="My Location" />
```